# Cannot get Azure DevOps to recognise and run my NUnit tests

Tags: azure, nunit, azure-pipelines

I am trying to get my NUnit tests to run in an Azure DevOps pipeline. However even though I can see my project being built:

```
Done Building Project "D:\a\3\s\Src\Standard\Splyce.Standard.Common.Tests\Splyce.Standard.Common.Tests.csproj" (default targets).
```

I still get the following:

```
##[warning]No test assemblies found matching the pattern: **\*test*.dll,!**\*TestAdapter.dll,!**\obj\**.
```

I followed the instructions from https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/357521/view.html to add a "vsTest - Test Assemblies" step, and did not change any settings.

My test project does include the NUnit3 Test Adapter:

[image: Test Adapter]

So I am pretty sure this is only a pathing problem. However the globbing on the assembly selector should work to find it. This is my on disk folder structure for the solution in question:

**UPDATE: Show physical on disk layout includes Src.**

```
E:.
+---BuildProcessTemplates
\---Src
    +---AgentApiServer
    |   +---Splyce.AgentApi.Common
    |   |   +---bin
    |   |   |   \---Debug
    |   |   |       \---netcoreapp2.1
    |   |   +---MirrorEngine
    |   |   |   \---Framework
    |   |   |       +---Dtos
    |   |   |       +---Enums
    |   |   |       +---Events
    |   |   |       \---Interfaces
    |   |   \---obj
    |   |       \---Debug
    |   |           \---netcoreapp2.1
    |   \---Splyce.AgentApi.Server
    |       +---bin
    |       |   \---Debug
    |       |       +---netcoreapp2.0
    |       |       +---netcoreapp2.1
    |       |       \---netcoreapp2.2
    |       +---obj
    |       |   \---Debug
    |       |       +---netcoreapp2.0
    |       |       +---netcoreapp2.1
    |       |       \---netcoreapp2.2
    |       +---Properties
    |       \---wwwroot
    \---Standard
        +---Common
        +---packages
        |   +---NUnit.3.11.0
        |   |   +---build
        |   |   \---lib
        |   |       +---net20
        |   |       +---net35
        |   |       +---net40
        |   |       +---net45
        |   |       +---netstandard1.4
        |   |       \---netstandard2.0
        |   +---NUnit3TestAdapter.3.13.0
        |   |   \---build
        |   |       +---net35
        |   |       \---netcoreapp1.0
        |   \---Shouldly.3.0.2
        |       \---lib
        |           +---net40
        |           +---net451
        |           +---netstandard1.3
        |           \---netstandard2.0
        +---Splyce.Standard.Common
        |   +---bin
        |   |   \---Debug
        |   |       \---netstandard2.0
        |   +---Helpers
        |   \---obj
        |       \---Debug
        |           \---netstandard2.0
        +---Splyce.Standard.Common.Tests
        |   +---bin
        |   |   +---Debug
        |   |   \---Release
        |   +---obj
        |   |   \---Debug
        |   |       \---TempPE
        |   \---Properties
        +---Splyce.Standard.DbMigrations
        |   +---bin
        |   |   \---Debug
        |   |       \---netstandard2.0
        |   +---Dtos
        |   +---Framework
        |   |   +---DbUp
        |   |   +---Dtos
        |   |   |   \---DatabaseMigrationsManager
        |   |   +---Enums
        |   |   \---Events
        |   \---obj
        |       \---Debug
        |           \---netstandard2.0
        +---Splyce.Standard.Messaging
        |   +---bin
        |   |   \---Debug
        |   |       \---netstandard2.0
        |   +---Client
        |   |   +---Publisher
        |   |   \---Subscriber
        |   +---Framework
        |   |   +---Interfaces
        |   |   \---Messages
        |   +---Messages
        |   |   +---Health
        |   |   \---Mirroring
        |   \---obj
        |       \---Debug
        |           \---netstandard2.0
        \---UnitTestProject1
            +---bin
            |   \---Debug
            |       \---netcoreapp2.2
            \---obj
                \---Debug
                    \---netcoreapp2.2
```

Can anyone give me any ideas here on how to get Azure to find my test assemblies.

Comment: are the resulting dlls called something like `*test*.dll`?

Comment: Yes Splyce.Standard.Common.Tests for example.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing a similar issue, but the root cause ended up being related to the msbuildArgs parameter on my VSBuild task being set to '/target:Publish'. The VSBuild log was letting me know the project was unpublishable, and that was also preventing it from building.

> Done Building Project "D:\BuildAgents\Agent03_work\1\s\Calculators\Calculators.csproj" (Publish target(s)).
> Project "D:\BuildAgents\Agent03_work\1\s\Workbench.sln" (1) is building "D:\BuildAgents\Agent03_work\1\s\Calculators.Tests\Calculators.Tests.csproj" (5) on node 1 (Publish target(s)).
> _DeploymentUnpublishable:
> Skipping unpublishable project.
> Done Building Project "D:\BuildAgents\Agent03_work\1\s\Calculators.Tests\Calculators.Tests.csproj" (Publish target(s)).

My resolution was just to add an additional build task. Here's my updated yaml:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    vsVersion: '16.0'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: '**\*Test*.dll'
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    vsVersion: '16.0'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    msbuildArgs: '/target:Publish'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Followed by CopyFiles and PublishBuildArtifacts tasks.

Comment: Thank you for this workaround. Does this build the solution twice? Seems very inefficient...

Comment: I found out that you can specify both Build and Publish targets in MSBuild like so: /target:Build;Publish. This will avoid having to do multiple builds.

Answer (score 0):

What's the root folder for your search? By default that's also the root folder used to look up Test Adapters. The default is the Repository Root, but since you're building a specific `csproj` I suspect you may have scoped this to the project root instead of the solution root.

[image]

You can override to a more specific path for the test adapters:

[image]

You should probably stick something like: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\packages\` in there.

If your project is .NET Core, you can also try running a `dotnet test` task instead of `vstest`.

Comment: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\packages\ produces error that the packages folder does not exist. I cannot seem to find what the various variables are so I can try others. Test project is .NET 4.6.1 testing a .NET Standard 2.0 class library.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables

Comment: Make that Build.SourcesDirectory instead.

Comment: That was my bad I had $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\packages and that failed. Looking at the output I figured out that $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Src\Standard\packages is probably what it needs to be. Now while Azure things the path exists  (so no error) I still get no tests built. I have updated my on disk layout because I suspect that because the solution(s) are in folders this is causing an issue. Or perhaps I need to provide a root base folder of \Src?

Comment: Have you tried pointing to a very specific package int he packages folder, or using a script to copy the dlls into the bin folder of the test project?